# Check if string is in array inside dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a dictionary of strings to arrays of strings: `{"a":["b", "c"]}`. When indexing into the dictionary, I get an array of strings back, but checking if any string is in this array always returns false.
Here is the code setup:

```
var dict = {
    "first":["a", "b", "c"]
}
if("a" in dict["first"]){
    // Never hits this line
    console.log("Found a!");
}
```

I'm pretty new to Javascript so I may be missing something about the setup of a dictionary object, but it seems pretty straightforward and I have professional experience in a few C languages so it is fairly disconcerting that this doesn't work. What is wrong here?

Comment: The `in` operator checks for properties, like `"first" in dict` or `"0" in dict.first`. You want to check whether the array [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) an element

Comment: The supposed "duplicate" question is not the same!

Comment: @ Dagrooms: How does any of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/1048572) not help you to check whether a string is in an array? Whether the array is part of a dictionary does absolutely not matter for your question. Or are you actually asking why the `in` operator doesn't do what you think it should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object, [Taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

`a` is not a property it's an array value, array index is act as property and `0 in dict["first"]` will be `true`  here. So here you can use **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**

```js
var dict = {
  "first": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
if (dict["first"].indexOf("a") > -1) {
  console.log("Found a!");
}
```

Comment: What a life saver. It was marked as duplicate but the duplicate question was not nearly the same answer, and I don't want to use jquery in this application.

Answer (score 0):

> try this. this will work to you.

```
var dict = {
    "first":["c", "b", "a"]
};
console.log(dict.first);
for( var x in dict.first){

    if(dict.first[x]=="a")
    {
     console.log("index of a :"+ x);
     break;
    }
}
}
```